# Getting Mongo DB users in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there any way to get the users and passwords created in MongoDB from Java? I am trying to write an encryption utility which will then encrypt the usernames and passwords. I went through the Driver documentation for Java but didn't find anything relevant.

Thanks

Boris

Answer (score 0):

User/password stored in collection of `system.users` per mongoDB database, just query it as query normal collection. But normally you can't get the original password because it has been converted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks... That works but as you said the password is stored in encrypted format. I am writing a script that will create the users and the roles and encrypt it and store it in a different collection. So I was thinking of implementing the encryption part as a separate utility, in Java, which can be run after the automated scripts (which are nothing but Mongo shell commands in Javascript) have run. Now i need to figure out a way to invoke the utility at the time of user creation i.e from Javascript or to implement the encryption in Javascript itself. I'll post the solution once i figure it out.

Thanks Again!!!!